# we could have written the following and BE RETURNED the same result set (grammar)

Tags: grammar

*When there is only one instance of the column name in the query, then qualifying column names becomes optional. Thus, we could have written the following and **be returned** the same result set...*

I can't understand how ***be returned*** is worked into the sentence. Is it *we could be returned the same result set* or what? Who's the subject of ***be***? Please, break it down for me.

Comment: For what it's worth, I would have considered `been returned` more idiomatically correct to match "could have" ... though this may be a matter of programmer idiom rather than English idiom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"we could be returned the same result set" is correct, and the subject of this action is whatever is doing the returning. "We" is the indirect object - the receiver of the result set.

This is not standard usage, however.

"to return" normally takes a direct object:

> the **book** was returned to me
>
> the **result set** will be returned to us

Even the definition "**to bring in (as profit) :  yield**" should have a direct object.

What I would have expected using the same wording would be

> ...and have the same result set returned to us

The only reason I can think the author has phrased it the way they have is to completely exclude the implication that returning of the result set is a purposeful action. In fact, they have omitted any mention of the doer at all  (hence my "whatever is doing the returning" above). They have also avoided mention of themselves as the recipient by not using "have [x] returned to us". This is like a super-passive - it seems they want to focus entirely on the fact that the result set is automatically generated by a system whether there is a recipient or not, perhaps with the [noun "return"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/return) in mind, as in "tax returns"

Answer (score 0):

*Thus, we could have written the following and be returned the same result set...*

If you turn this around it is easier to understand:

> Thus, we could have written the following and the same result set
>   [would] be returned [to us]

Or:

> Thus, we could have written the following and the same result set
>   [would have] be[en] returned [to us]

*Be returned* is a [passive](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv65.shtml) construction. *The result set* is the subject of the sentence: it is being returned by a  person/company who is not present.

Here's how it would work in an active construction:

> John/The company [subject] returned the same result set [object] to
>   us.